# how to set a unique aws S3 file name?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mongoose

I'm sending my file to an s3 bucket through the front end, as that seems more efficient from what i've read.

But, for some of my schemas / collections, I will not have the id for which the file / photo is associated -- as they are being created the same time as the upload:

```
  $scope.add = function(){

  if($scope.file.photo){
      $scope.distiller.photo = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/whiskey-upload/distillers/' 
      + ' needs to be assigned to guid or collection id'
        Distillery.create($scope.distiller).then(function(res){
          console.log(res);
          $scope.distillers.push(res.data.distiller);
      var files = $scope.file;
      var filename = files.photo.$ngfName;
      var type = files.type;
      var folder = 'distillers/';

      var query = {
          files: files,
          folder: folder,
          filename: res.data.distiller._id,
          type: type
        };

        Uploads.awsUpload(query).then(function(){
          $scope.distiller = {};
          $scope.file = {};
        });
    });
  }
  else{
    Distillery.create($scope.distiller).then(function(res){
      toastr.success('distillery created without photo');
      $scope.distiller = {};
    });
  }
  };
```

The above code wouldn't work, unless I sent an update on the aws.Upload promise after the distillery object was created and after the file was uploaded to s3.

That doesn't seem efficient.

I could create a guid and assign that to the s3 file name, and also keep a reference of that on the distillery object. This seems hacky, though.

example Guid creator:

```
    function guid() {
  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
  }
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}
```

What would be the cleanest way to achieve what I want?

Comment: You may want to look into using a package like fineuploader

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good GUID generator is a very standard way to solve a unique id problem. Depending on the algorithm, the chance of a name collision could be close to nil.  As you know, JavaScript does not have a native one, so one like yours is reasonable. I don't think its hacky at all.

Here is another by [@briguy37](https://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/2MVFd/):

```
function generateUUID() {
     var d = new Date().getTime();
     var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
         var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
         d = Math.floor(d/16);
        return (c=='x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
     });
     return uuid; };
```

Comment: how close to nil would it be? let's say I had an app like instagram?

Comment: "Assuming uniform probability for simplicity, the probability of one duplicate would be about 50% if every person on earth as of 2014 owned 600 million GUIDs." Not sure I understand that probability, but it seems low. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier for more info.

Comment: So if that were the case, you'd be, practically, guaranteed to have a duplicate. Since the probability of a duplicate is 50%, you're expected to have a collision after 2 new GUIDs.

Comment: The probability reaches 50% when every person on earth as of 2014 owns 600 million GUIDs... each.